# Polar coordinates and circular player scrub

Tags: javascript, math, radians

I'm having issues positioning the cursor at the right point in this circular time scrubber:

[image]

I'm calculating angle with simple formula: `Math.atan2(y, x)`.

This gives me the angle in radians, then I map it to a range `[0, 1]`.
This range updates the player progress which is binded back to the cursor position (simple bi-directional binding).

What I need to do is just have `angle = 0rad`, when `mouse.x = 0` and `mouse.y >= radius`.

Right now angle is set to 0 when I'm at `mouse.x >= rootRadius`, and `mouse.y = 0`.

This image perhaps add more insight, I'm having difficult explaining it in a simple manner, however this should be `progress/angle = 0`:

[image]

Comment: If I've understood the problem correctly, you need to rotate the coordinate system by 90 degrees anti-clockwise, i.e. use `angle = Math.atan2(-x, y)`

Comment: thanks! that's what I want to achieve (rotate coordinate system by -90), but, unluckily it doesn't work like suggested.